# How to count values for columns in a groupby dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

So I'm having trouble with this one:

[image]

Ive tried this, but it stacks time:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Time'])
for group, data in df2:
    result =  data.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T.stack()
    print(result)
```

Comment: https://uscript.co/public/annoym/python/a484328e.py

Comment: Thats good, but I have like 100 columns; how can I implement that in a loop...for now, I have this working (ignoring the first result for 'Time'):         
<br/>


`df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Time': ['T0', 'T0', 'T1', 'T1'],
  'Health': ['Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
  'Meds': ['Good', 'Bad', 'Good', 'Good']
})
for key, value in df.iteritems():
    result = df.groupby(['Time', key]).size().unstack(0).fillna(0)
    print(result)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the values of `Time` as the new columns and the values of the other columns as new index. If you had just a few columns, this could be easily achieved by a `pivot_table`. E.g. for `'Health'`:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([['T0', 'Yes', 'Good'], ['T0', 'Yes', 'Bad'], ['T1', 'No', 'Good'], ['T1', 'No', 'Good']], columns=['Time', 'Health', 'Meds'])    

In [18]: pd.pivot_table(df[['Health', 'Time']], index='Health', columns='Time', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)                                                                                                      
Out[18]: 
Time    T0  T1
Health        
No       0   2
Yes      2   0
```

However, you want to repeat that procedure for all columns. This is also possible with a pivot table, given you reshape your dataframe into a long data format. This means you create a new column with all column names and is exactly what the `stack()` function is for:

```
In [45]: df_stacked = df.set_index('Time').stack().rename('value').reset_index()                                                                                                                                                
Out[45]: 
  Time level_1 value
0   T0  Health   Yes
1   T0    Meds  Good
2   T0  Health   Yes
3   T0    Meds   Bad
4   T1  Health    No
5   T1    Meds  Good
6   T1  Health    No
7   T1    Meds  Good
```

Now you can pivot the stacked dataframe in order to use both, the values of the column with all column names and their values as index

```
In [48]: pd.pivot_table(df_stacked, index=['level_1', 'value'], columns='Time', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)                                                                                                      
Out[48]: 
Time           T0  T1
level_1 value        
Health  No      0   2
        Yes     2   0
Meds    Bad     1   0
        Good    1   2
```

The description is probably a bit confusing but I hope the code makes it clear. You basically had the right ingredients but the combination is a bit tricky.

Comment: Beautiful. I wanted to do this without using a for loop.